# Main oven tripping

Tags: oven

The main oven trips the house main circuit breaker but the small oven works fine. I’ve tested the elements which are ok and then disconnected the fan but the oven still trips. Now at a loss as to what is wrong, the oven is approx 18 month old. Could anybody have any ideas please

Comment: What make and model is the oven that's doing this?

Comment: Fan would likely have nothing to do with it. Elements (bake & broil) are the main draw in general and if they fail the wrong way will trip breakers. Make & model, plus size of oven breaker & main breaker?

Comment: It's nice you've isolated the problem.  Look for a short to ground in the main oven wiring.  A melted wire...a piece of tinfoil bridging a terminal...a wire that fell off a terminal....

Comment: *I’ve tested the elements which are ok* How? Resistance?

Comment: The breaker trips *even with the elements removed*?  If so, then it is something shorted in the oven wiring or in the control panel.